# LAN back to normal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way that when I turn a world to LAN in Minecraft, I can make it normal again? Basically, can I un-LAN a world? Frankly, I'm new to the multiplayer aspect of Minecraft, and have NO idea what I'm doing....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just quit your world and re-enter it. It should work, since the server gets shut down and resets everytime the world is quit.